# Before and after lowercase and uppercase letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, enumerate

I am trying to uppercase letters before and after a specific letter in a list. Uppercase any letter before and after
uppercase the previous and next letters that come before and after each "u".

For list 1, I need to uppercase letters before and after "u" not uppercase "u".

```
lst1 = []
for wrd in capitals:
    wrd = wrd.lower()
    for idx, letter in enumerate(wrd):
        if letter == 'u':
            if idx-1 > 0 and wrd[idx - 1] != 'u':
                wrd = wrd.replace(wrd[idx - 1], wrd[idx - 1].upper())
            if idx+1 < len(wrd) and wrd[idx + 1] != 'u':
                wrd = wrd.replace(wrd[idx + 1], wrd[idx + 1].upper())
    if "u" in wrd:
        lst1.append(wrd)

print(lst1)
```

original list:

```
['Kabul', 'Luanda', 'Buenos Aires', 'Baku', 'Nassau', 'Brussels', 'Thimphu', 'Sucre', 'Ouagadougou', 'Yaounde', 'Bangui', 'Yamoussoukro', 'Prague', 'Djibouti', 'Roseau', 'Quito', 'Suva', 'Banjul', 'Guatemala City', 'Bissau', 'Port au Prince', 'Tegucigalpa', 'Budapest', 'Dublin', 'Jerusalem', 'Nur-Sultan', 'Kuwait City', 'Beirut', 'Maseru', 'Vaduz', 'Vilnius', 'Luxembourg', 'Kuala Lumpur', 'Majuro', 'Nouakchott', 'Port Louis', 'Chisinau', 'Ulaanbaatar', 'Maputo', 'Kathmandu', 'Managua', 'Abuja', 'Muscat', 'Asuncion', 'Bucharest', 'Edinburgh', 'Ljubljana', 'Mogadishu', 'Seoul', 'Juba', 'Khartoum', 'Damascus', 'Dushanbe', "Nuku'alofa", 'Tunis', 'Funafuti', 'Abu Dhabi', 'Lusaka']
```

It prints this:

```
['kaBuL', 'luAndA', 'buEnos airEs', 'baKu', 'nAssAu', 'bRuSSelS', 'tHimpHu', 'suCre', 'OuAGAdOuGOu', 'yaOuNde', 'banGuI', 'yamOuSSOuKrO', 'praGuE', 'djibOuTi', 'roseAu', 'quIto', 'suVa', 'banJuL', 'guAtemAlA city', 'bissAu', 'port Au prince', 'teGuCiGalpa', 'buDapest', 'duBlin', 'jeRuSalem', 'nuR-SuLtan', 'kuWait city', 'beiRuT', 'maseRu', 'vaDuZ', 'vIlnIuS', 'luXembOuRg', 'kuALA LuMPuR', 'maJuRo', 'nOuAkchOtt', 'pOrt lOuIs', 'chisinAu', 'uLaanbaatar', 'maPuTo', 'kathmanDu', 'mAnAGuA', 'aBuJa', 'muScat', 'aSuNcioN', 'buCharest', 'edinBuRgh', 'lJuBlJana', 'mogadisHu', 'seOuL', 'juBa', 'khartOuM', 'damaSCuS', 'duShanbe', "nuKu'alofa", 'tuNis', 'FuNaFuTi', 'aBu dhaBi', 'luSaka']
```

I need this:

```
['kaBuL', 'LuAnda', 'BuEnos aires', 'baKu', 'nassAu', 'bRuSsels', 'thimpHu', 'SuCre', 'OuAgadOuGOu', 'yaOuNde', 'banGuI', 'yamOuSsOuKro', 'praGuE', 'djibOuTi', 'roseAu', 'QuIto', 'SuVa', 'banJuL', 'GuAtemala city', 'bissAu', 'port Au prince', 'teGuCigalpa', 'BuDapest', 'DuBlin', 'jeRuSalem', 'NuR-SuLtan', 'KuWait city', 'beiRuT', 'maseRu', 'vaDuZ', 'vilnIuS', 'LuXembOuRg', 'KuAla LuMPuR', 'maJuRo', 'nOuAkchott', 'port lOuIs', 'chisinAu', 'uLaanbaatar', 'maPuTo', 'kathmanDu', 'manaGuA', 'aBuJa', 'MuScat', 'aSuNcion', 'BuCharest', 'edinBuRgh', 'lJuBljana', 'mogadisHu', 'seOuL', 'JuBa', 'khartOuM', 'damasCuS', 'DuShanbe', "NuKu'alofa", 'TuNis', 'FuNaFuTi', 'aBu dhabi', 'LuSaka']
```

Comment: Why is "vadUz" correct? Shouldn't it be "vaDUz" according to your rules? And "brAZZAville"?If not please update/clarify your question.

Comment: `word.replace()` replaces all occurrences of a letter, not just the one at the current index in the loop.

Comment: I suggest you write an `uppercase_index(string, index)` function. Then you can use `wrd = uppercase_index(wrd, idx+1)`

Answer (score 0):

So according to the "new" rules, i updated my code:

```
search_dict = {
    "u": ['Kabul', 'Luanda', 'Buenos Aires', 'Baku', 'Nassau', 'Brussels', 'Thimphu', 'Sucre', 'Ouagadougou', 'Yaounde',
          'Bangui', 'Yamoussoukro', 'Prague', 'Djibouti', 'Roseau', 'Quito', 'Suva', 'Banjul', 'Guatemala City',
          'Bissau', 'Port au Prince', 'Tegucigalpa', 'Budapest', 'Dublin', 'Jerusalem', 'Nur-Sultan', 'Kuwait City',
          'Beirut', 'Maseru', 'Vaduz', 'Vilnius', 'Luxembourg', 'Kuala Lumpur', 'Majuro', 'Nouakchott', 'Port Louis',
          'Chisinau', 'Ulaanbaatar', 'Maputo', 'Kathmandu', 'Managua', 'Abuja', 'Muscat', 'Asuncion', 'Bucharest',
          'Edinburgh', 'Ljubljana', 'Mogadishu', 'Seoul', 'Juba', 'Khartoum', 'Damascus', 'Dushanbe', "Nuku'alofa",
          'Tunis', 'Funafuti', 'Abu Dhabi', 'Lusaka'],
    # and so on...
}

result = [["".join(
    [let.upper() if pos in [f for idx, letter in enumerate(word.lower()) if letter == search_let for f in (idx + 1, idx - 1)] and let != search_let else let.lower() for pos, let in enumerate(word.lower())])
    for word in capitals]for search_let, capitals in search_dict.items()]

print(result)
```

Comparing results:

```
# This list is your expected list from the question
check = ['kaBuL', 'LuAnda', 'BuEnos aires', 'baKu', 'nassAu', 'bRuSsels', 'thimpHu', 'SuCre', 'OuAgadOuGOu', 'yaOuNde', 'banGuI', 'yamOuSsOuKro', 'praGuE', 'djibOuTi', 'roseAu', 'QuIto', 'SuVa', 'banJuL', 'GuAtemala city', 'bissAu', 'port Au prince', 'teGuCigalpa', 'BuDapest', 'DuBlin', 'jeRuSalem', 'NuR-SuLtan', 'KuWait city', 'beiRuT', 'maseRu', 'vaDuZ', 'vilnIuS', 'LuXembOuRg', 'KuAla LuMPuR', 'maJuRo', 'nOuAkchott', 'port lOuIs', 'chisinAu', 'uLaanbaatar', 'maPuTo', 'kathmanDu', 'manaGuA', 'aBuJa', 'MuScat', 'aSuNcion', 'BuCharest', 'edinBuRgh', 'lJuBljana', 'mogadisHu', 'seOuL', 'JuBa', 'khartOuM', 'damasCuS', 'DuShanbe', "NuKu'alofa", 'TuNis', 'FuNaFuTi', 'aBu dhabi', 'LuSaka']

for a, b in zip(check, result[0]):
    print(f"Expected: {a}" + " " * (20 - len(a)) + f"got: {b}" + " " * (20 - len(b)) + f"{a == b}")

print(all([a == b for a, b in zip(check, result[0])]))
```

You can add to the dictionary as many values as you want. Also the list comprhension is a little shorter now. It is not the most efficient, since it generates the required indices for every letter. This can be prevented by generating the indices before the list comprehension.

**Edge cases:**

1. "Port au Prince" (or Abu Dhabi) if you expect "port Au Prince"
   (ignoring spaces), you would need to strip the word first (or change
   the index computation).
2. "Nuku' Alofa" similar case, you would need to strip `'` first.

**Explanation**

You have to read this/a list comprehension backwards:

This iterates through the dictionary and gets each letter and the list of capitals:

```
for search_let, capitals in search_dict.items()
```

Next, we iterate through the list of capitals and get each capital (we do this for every (key, value)-pair in the dictionary):

```
for word in capitals
```

After skipping a small part (better for understanding), we generate each index of letters next to the search letter in the given capital:

```
[f for idx, letter in enumerate(word.lower()) if letter == search_let for f in (idx + 1, idx - 1)]
```

Then we check if the position of the current letter is part of the list we generated:

```
if pos in [list of indices]
```

And we have to check that the current letter is not our search letter:

```
and let != search_let
```

If that is the case, we add an uppercase letter to our output, else a lowercase letter:

```
[let.upper() if pos in [list of indices] and let != search_let else let.lower()
```

Last, we convert the output back to a string (we used a list comprehension, so it was a list before):

```
"".join(output list)
```

Everything else is just ordering and list comprehension stuff.

Comment: It appears that it's not supposed to uppercase the letter itself. He has a specific check `and wrd[idx - 1] != 'u'`

Comment: Why is he expecting "vadUz" then? Since "u" is a searched character. If he wouldn't want them to be uppercase, it would be easy to implement though.

Comment: That's in the loop where `z` is the letter to uppercase before/after.

Comment: I have no clue which rules apply now, i will let my solutions rest, until there is a clarification from his side.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. To clarify: for list 1 I need to uppercase letters before and after "u" not "u": for second list I need to uppercase letters before and after "z" not "z" it is working. for third list  I need to uppercase letters before and after "w" not "w"

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clarifying. I will update my response later, it should work tho if you change search_letters and words according to your requirements,

Comment: @Honn I tried changing search_letters and words like you suggested but I still can't get it right.

Comment: @Riel Should work now. Also added a dict for easier use with multiple values. There is an explanation and a better code now.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def uppercase_before_and_after_letter(s, letter):
    characters = list(s)
    for i, char in enumerate(s):
        if char == letter:
            prev, nxt = i - 1, i + 1
            if prev >= 0:
                characters[prev] = characters[prev].upper()
            if nxt < len(s):
                characters[nxt] = characters[nxt].upper()
    return "".join(characters)
```

then use it like this:

```py
print([uppercase_before_and_after_letter(word, "z") for word in ['brAzzAville', 'zAgreb', 'vadUz']])
```